# Repeating Notifications Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have notification that works well with only one time item. I need show my notification: 10:00 PM and 10:30 PM. How i can do that? Please tell me

My code:

NotificationManager.swift:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager
{
static let shared = NotificationManager()
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

func registerNotifications()
{
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert], completionHandler: {( granted, error) in })
}

func addNotificationWithCalendarTrigger(hour: Int, minute: Int)
{
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Hi"
    content.body = "It,s new notification!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var components = DateComponents()

    components.hour = hour
    components.minute = minute

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "calendar", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        //handle error
    }
}
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timeForNotifications()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func timeForNotifications()
{        
    NotificationManager.shared.addNotificationWithCalendarTrigger(hour: 22, minute: 00)
}

}
```

Comment: you never set the delegate 
center.delegate = self
also do not forget to set UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate for the class

Answer (score 0):

might be a bit late but I think this is what you're looking for. You can set the notification to show up at 10:00 with the following code:

```
var components = DateComponents()

components.hour = 22
components.minute = 00

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "calendar", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

What I always do is replace components with date, but I think your option works as well.

```
var date = DateComponents()
date.hour = 22
date.minute = 00
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
```

Hope this helped you out!